# Login Action changes in single script and update same in multiple scripts with out open each and every script in Loadrunner tool

Tags: authentication, loadrunner

I need one help,

I have around 50 LR scripts in one of my application which is common action (Login part) in all scripts. From this Action few requests are changing on each code deployment. To open and update changes in each script will take more time and delay in execution.

Do we have any option to save efforts for this challenge.

Thanks & Regards
Narasimha

Answer (score 0):

This is code.   Code maintenance takes between 30-50% of the time required to initially develop the code.   Are you exceeding this value?

You might also consider that this one action that is common can bew pulled into a library, a common header file for reference in each script.

```
include myfuncs.h
```

Have a function in your own header file which contains the login code.  This .h file, once modified, will likely need to be sent to a common location accessible to all of your load generators or loaded into a directory of a common name on each load generator